# Reading a xml file remotely

Tags: xml

I have a standalone Java based desktop application. This application uses a property file (in simple text format) which needs to updated periodically.
To do that, this application should connect to a remote server , read a xml file located there and update my property file based on the data in the xml.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of class url

```
URL url = new URL("http://yourremoteserver.com/file_to_be_read.xml");
 URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
```